# ToolTip doesn't work on WPF Run object

Tags: c#, wpf

This is the code:

```
<Border x:Name="GlobalBorder" IsEnabled="False">
    <RichTextBox/>
</Border>
```

When I click a button I do `GlobalBorder.IsEnabled = true`, and it works.
After, I insert programmatically some Run objects in the RichTextBox.
The problem is tooltips of the Run objects didn't work.
But if I remove the line of xaml `IsEnabled="False"` the tooltip work.
P.S. I before enable the border, and I add the Run objects after that.

Edit: 
If I set `GlobalBorder.IsEnabled = false` programmatically (in the constructor of the Window) instead of doing it with xaml, the tooltip work!
It's a mystery... for me!

I add the Run object in this way:

```
FlowDocument document = TargetTextBox.Document;
Paragraph paragraph = document.Blocks.ElementAt(0) as Paragraph;
Run itemText = new Run("$" + componente.ItemComponente.IdComponenteTN.ToString() + "$");
itemText.ToolTip = componente.ItemComponente.Descrizione;
paragraph.Inlines.Add(itemText);
```

But, as I said, only if disable the Border with xaml the tooltip doesn't work.

Comment: try `GlobalBorder.SetValue(Border.IsEnabledProperty, false);` if not working put your insert code

Comment: Can you post the code that you use for inserting `Run` objects?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.isenabled(v=vs.110).aspx): UIElements which have `IsEnabled` property set to false, **do not participate** in hit testing or focus and therefore will not be sources of input events - no matter if you set the property either in your XAML or in your code.

Your `Run` objects are inside a disabled control, so they do not raise `MouseEnter` event and their ToolTips can't become visible. If you want to have ToolTips, you should consider using `ReadOnly` property of `RichTextBox` instead of `IsEnabled` property of `Border` element.

Comment: The problem is Tooltip is not visible when I enable the Border element.

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't understand what you mean. `Visibility` is a dependecy property so is not important _when_ you change it. `IsEnabled` property has the same behaviour.

Comment: Initially the Border is disabled (in the xaml code), then I enable it and I insert some Run objects (with ToolTip) in the RichTextBox. Result: the tooltips are not visible. If I do the same thing, but setting 'GlobalBorder.IsEnabled = false' programmatically in the constructor of the Window, it works (the tooltips are visible).

Comment: Can you post the code of both cases (the first one with the border disabile in XAML and the second one with `GlobalBorder.IsEnabled = false` in the constructor) please?

Answer (score 0):

You might try putting [ToolTipService.ShowOnDisabled](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.tooltipservice.showondisabled.aspx) in the Border element:

```
<Border x:Name="GlobalBorder"
        IsEnabled="False"
        ToolTipService.ShowOnDisabled="True">
    <RichTextBox/>
</Border>
```